# Python Directory Hell

Tags: python

Here's my directory structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── foo.py
│   │   └── bar.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── faz.py
│   │   └── baz.py
│   └── main.py
├── tests
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── test_foo.py
│   │   └── test_bar.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── test_faz.py
│   │   └── test_baz.py
```

My `src/helpers/__init__.py` looks like the following:

```py
from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar
```

And the `src/services/__init__.py` looks like:

```py
from .faz import Faz
from .baz import Baz
```

My `src/main.py`:

```py
import helpers

f = helpers.Foo()
```

My `tests/helpers/test_foo.py`:

```py
import src.helpers as helpers

def test_foo():
    f = helpers.Foo()
```

All of this **works**.

However, in my problem is when, let's say, `src\services\faz.py` *references* `src\helpers\foo.py`.

Currently, `...\faz.py` looks like the following:

```py
import helpers

class Faz():
   def DoSomething(self):
      # something
```

This works if I run `python src/main.py`.  But if I run `coverage run -m pytest`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'`. If I change the import statement to `import src.helpers`, the tests works but the application no longer does.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to turn this into an installable python package. Instead of hacking paths you just do normal python package imports. Assuming this product is named "foopackage" you can add src/foopackage and include a setup.py file.

```
├── src
│   ├── foopackage
│   │   ├── helpers
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── foo.py
│   │   │   └── bar.py
│   │   └── services
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── faz.py
│   │       └── baz.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── main.py
├── tests
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── test_foo.py
│   │   └── test_bar.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── test_faz.py
│   │   └── test_baz.py
├── setup.py
```

You can package your product with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or other option. Or do a "development" install. Setup a python virtual environment and when you want to test, at the root of this directory do `pip install -e .` ("editable" sets it up so that python grabs your package from this local directory instead of the regular python module directory). Now something like `nose` or `pytest` can scan the tree for anything called test_xxx.py and run it.

`main.py`, scripts, and the various test modules would all just

```
import foopackage.helpers as helpers
```

src/services/faz.py would

```
from .. import helpers
```

Python packaging is something of a dark art, but a minimalist `setup.py` would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='foopackage',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='Foo all the Bars',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    scripts=['src/scripts/main.py']
)
```

Comment: thanks! I'm new to python. So, in this scenario, what is the proper way to execute "main.py"? Is it as simple as `python ./src/scripts/main.py`? Or, is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on operating system and how you install. If you are on a unix system, add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of main, `chmod +x main.py` and then `pip install`, it will be copied to `~/.local/bin` and you can just type `main.py`. If you do a `pip install -e ...` or a "develop" install with setup.py, then you can add your script path to your local PATH variable and do the same thing.

Comment: thanks again. in my `main.py`, what path do i use to import `foopackage/helpers/foo`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...For those of you who stumble on this:

Because `helpers` and `services` are seen as two different modules, python doesn't allow referencing above the module level.  Running `python ./src/main.py` works because the module is `main.py`, however, `pytest` tests sees only a `helpers` module and `services` module.

The key is to add the following code to the `__init__.py` in the `services` folder (in my case, the services are referencing the helpers) so that the parent folder is included in the search path.

```py
# src/services/__init__.py
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

Now all scripts/modules in the `services` folder can import modules from the `helpers` folder.